# Building model takes so much time in Cplex

Tags: optimization, cplex, gams, c#

I am a beginner in CPLEX. I have a model with about 1 million constants and 800k rows and 1.6 million columns. I implemented in both GAMS and CPLEX (C# as the platform). The final solution for both is the same but the computational time for building the model (before solve) in CPLEX is much more than GAMS( about 2 hours vs 30 seconds). I have no idea why it happens and how it can be solved.
A sample as coding one of my constraints is as follows in C#.

```
for (int ss = 1; ss <= s; ss++) {
    for (int tt = 1; tt <= t; tt++) {
        if (ss != source && ss != sink) {
            string c1 = "const01(" + (ss) + "," + (tt).ToString() + "): ";
            ILinearNumExpr eq01 = MODEL.LinearNumExpr();
                                    
             for (int nn = 1; nn <= n; nn++) {
                 if (nbels[nn, ss] == 1 && pdw[nn, ss] > 0) {
                     eq01.AddTerm(1 / pdw[nn, ss], x[nn][ss][tt]);
                 }
             }
             eq01.AddTerm(1, sVar01[ss][tt]);
             MODEL.AddEq(eq01, cap[ss, tt], c1);
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your question to make the C# code clearer.

Comment: @pouria, welcome to OR.SE. I am not sure about C#, but GAMS has a fast pre-processing step rather than. Other optimization python-based software.

Comment: I've done that. If you have a CPLEX license you might also be able to ask them about their C++ interface. The code itself doesn't give me enough information to say anything. But it is likely that you hit some $O(n^2)$ behavior. What version of cplex are you using?

Comment: I don't know much about C# but just a few observations: 1) Do you need to define a `string c1` name for the constraint? I think you can define your constraints without names. 2) Cant you use batch definition for your constraints? For example, rather than using `AddTerm`, is it possible to use `AddTerms` and get rid of a loop? 3) can you define a combo index first for `[ss][tt]`, define your variables and coefficients using that combo index, and consequently, remove one more loop?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @A.Omidi

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Cplex 12.8. @worldsmithhelper

Comment: @EhsanK Thank you for your reply. I deleted the name of the constraints and variables. but it doesn't have any significant improvement. Also based on your suggestion, I apply the AddTerms method, but the time of building the constraint get worth. About your 4th suggestion, because of the variable size and several conditions for each constraint, using a combo index is very hard for me. would you please tell me about the best way for using combo index which you used?

Comment: @puria, would you say please, which part of the contracting model gets much time to build the optimization process? Have you tried using an external database to read the MP data?

Comment: @pouriaarsalani it all comes down to the size of the set (in your case, size of `s`, `t`, and `n`) and in how many other constraints the same index is used. e.g. if you use $\forall s, t$ in several other constraints and you dont need all the combinations of `s` and `t`, then an index combo (especially a sparse one) can really help. btw, if `n` is large in your example, consider first creating your most inner loop separately and then add it in your `s,t` loop. Maybe that helps.